# The \newcommand question is farfetched, but $\LaTeX$ typing still takes ages

Tags: discussion, mathjax, newcommand

Everything is in the title. For now, I stop answering questions, it takes me too much time.

Comment: why ? Also it's MathJaX, an AJAX library simulating LaTeX, not actual LaTeX.

Comment: If you're typing on this site, it's not LaTeX at all.

Comment: This is a very terse post, and you leave it to the Reader's imagination what effect you expect by "set[ting] up Latex macros in the profile."   Probably what you want to accomplish is best approximated by a browser add-in, not by revamping the site's software.

Comment: See also [Specific Latex commands for user's account](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11870) and other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/11870).

Comment: I suppose that "the \newcommand question" in the [current version of the question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/30731/4)
refers to the [original version of your posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/30731/1). However, I'd guess that this could be rather unclear to people reading the question - unless they check the revision history. So it might be useful to clarify what you actually want to ask, if you plan to keep this question on the site.

Comment: It's not a question, but an observation: answering questions takes a long time. But maybe misunderstood the use of the meta section

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood the use of the meta section.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi then maybe we can delete the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand your post correctly, the problem you see is that answering takes a long time and the reason is that you don't have macros automatically at your disposal. (Of course, for other users there might be other factors which slow them down - but it seems that you have singled out that this particular things as a problem for you.)

If you have a few commands which you are used to and can't really efficiently write without them, you can simply copy-paste a block of newcommands at the beginning of the post. It is probably not an optimal solution - but I've seen users who do this. (Although this probably won't be feasible if the macros you need are in the range of hundreds.)

If this would be possibly useful for you, you could check also this post: [Bookmarklet plugin to speed up LaTeX macro typing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16802). Although it might take some time to get used to shortcuts implemented there. (I don't really know how difficult it would be to add your own shortcuts to the list.)

Personally, if I have at least slightly longer post I do not write it on site - I use an editor on my computer. The advantage being that I can used the keyboard shortcuts in the editor which I am used to.

I will also mention that I use newcommand in my post relatively often, especially if something repeats rather frequently in that particular post or if I am copy-pasting some parts from LaTeX source which I have used for some other purpose. In such cases, I checked which macros are needed when I am done and I include only those. (It's a bit of nuisance, but in some cases it outweighs the need to type longer expressions that can be shortened by the use of macros.)